# Optimizing T-SQL query which constracts the same subtable twice

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I want to optimize this query

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
          KladrItemName                 _KladrItemName
        , WordPositionKladrItem         _WordPositionKladrItem
        , WordPositionAddressString     _WordPositionAddressString
        , StartPosition                 _StartPosition
        , EndPosition                   _EndPosition
        , Metric                        _Metric
        , IsConstruction                _IsConstruction
        , WordsCount                    _WordsCount
        , Indeces                       _Indeces
        , WordPositionAddressString     _StartWordIndex
        , WordPositionAddressString     _EndWordIndex
        , 1                             _StepNumber
    FROM 
        (
        SELECT 
            dbo.tKladrItems.KladrItemName
            , dbo.tFoundWords.WordFromAddressString 
            , dbo.tFoundWords.WordFromKladr 
            , dbo.tFoundWords.WordPosition AS WordPositionAddressString
            , dbo.tWordKladrItems.wordNumber AS WordPositionKladrItem
            , dbo.tFoundWords.StartPosition
            , dbo.tFoundWords.EndPosition
            , dbo.tFoundWords.Metric
            , dbo.tFoundWords.IsConstruction
            , dbo.tKladrItems.WordsCount
            , dbo.tKladrItems.Indeces
        FROM
            dbo.tWordsFromKladr JOIN dbo.tWordKladrItems ON dbo.tWordsFromKladr.ID = dbo.tWordKladrItems.wordID 
            JOIN dbo.tFoundWords ON dbo.tFoundWords.WordFromKladr = dbo.tWordsFromKladr.WordFromKladr
            JOIN dbo.tKladrItems ON dbo.tWordKladrItems.kladrItemID = dbo.tKladrItems.id    
        )T
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
          KladrItemName
        , WordPositionKladrItem
        , WordPositionAddressString
        , CASE WHEN StartPosition  _EndPosition THEN EndPosition ELSE _EndPosition END -- MAX
        , CAST(Metric + _Metric AS numeric(20, 10))
        , IsConstruction + _IsConstruction
        , WordsCount
        , Indeces
        , CASE WHEN _StartWordIndex  WordPositionAddressString THEN _EndWordIndex ELSE WordPositionAddressString END
        , 1 + _StepNumber
    FROM 

        (
        SELECT 
            dbo.tKladrItems.KladrItemName
            , dbo.tFoundWords.WordFromAddressString 
            , dbo.tFoundWords.WordFromKladr 
            , dbo.tFoundWords.WordPosition AS WordPositionAddressString
            , dbo.tWordKladrItems.wordNumber AS WordPositionKladrItem
            , dbo.tFoundWords.StartPosition
            , dbo.tFoundWords.EndPosition
            , dbo.tFoundWords.Metric
            , dbo.tFoundWords.IsConstruction
            , dbo.tKladrItems.WordsCount
            , dbo.tKladrItems.Indeces
        FROM
            dbo.tWordsFromKladr JOIN dbo.tWordKladrItems ON dbo.tWordsFromKladr.ID = dbo.tWordKladrItems.wordID 
            JOIN dbo.tFoundWords ON dbo.tFoundWords.WordFromKladr = dbo.tWordsFromKladr.WordFromKladr
            JOIN dbo.tKladrItems ON dbo.tWordKladrItems.kladrItemID = dbo.tKladrItems.id
        ) AS Tab JOIN CTE ON
            Tab.KladrItemName = CTE._KladrItemName
        AND Tab.WordPositionKladrItem > CTE._WordPositionKladrItem
        AND Tab.WordPositionAddressString >  CTE._WordPositionAddressString
)
SELECT DISTINCT 

      _KladrItemName        KladrItemName
    , _StartPosition        StartPosition
    , _EndPosition          EndPosition
    , _Metric               SumMetric
    , _IsConstruction       SumIsConstruction
    , _Indeces              Indeces

FROM 
    CTE
WHERE 
    _StepNumber = _WordsCount
    AND (_IsConstruction = 0 or (_IsConstruction = 1 and _WordsCount > 1))
    AND _EndWordIndex - _StartWordIndex + 1 = _WordsCount
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

So that the table

```
SELECT 
            dbo.tKladrItems.KladrItemName
            , dbo.tFoundWords.WordFromAddressString 
            , dbo.tFoundWords.WordFromKladr 
            , dbo.tFoundWords.WordPosition AS WordPositionAddressString
            , dbo.tWordKladrItems.wordNumber AS WordPositionKladrItem
            , dbo.tFoundWords.StartPosition
            , dbo.tFoundWords.EndPosition
            , dbo.tFoundWords.Metric
            , dbo.tFoundWords.IsConstruction
            , dbo.tKladrItems.WordsCount
            , dbo.tKladrItems.Indeces
        FROM
            dbo.tWordsFromKladr JOIN dbo.tWordKladrItems ON dbo.tWordsFromKladr.ID = dbo.tWordKladrItems.wordID 
            JOIN dbo.tFoundWords ON dbo.tFoundWords.WordFromKladr = dbo.tWordsFromKladr.WordFromKladr
            JOIN dbo.tKladrItems ON dbo.tWordKladrItems.kladrItemID = dbo.tKladrItems.id
```

builds only once. But when I declare it as a temporary table, the execution time increases several times. Is there a way to optimize it by building this table once? Is there a way to optimaze it somehow else?

Thank you for help.

Comment: Please clean and reformat your sql it is impossible to read.. e.g., what is "dbo.tFoundWords.WordFromKladr "

Comment: Why don't you also clean and reformat your name. Maybe grow up a little.

Comment: I changed your user name for you.  Please be advised that profanity is strongly discouraged on Stack Overflow.  This is because the site is primarily used in the workplace, and we don't want to be blocked by anyone's company policies due to profanity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two CTEs in a statement.  Try this:

```
WITH Sub As
 (SELECT i.KladrItemName,
            f.WordFromAddressString, f.WordFromKladr,
            f.WordPosition WordPositionAddressString,
            wi.wordNumber WordPositionKladrItem,
            f.StartPosition, f.EndPosition, f.Metric, 
            f.IsConstruction, i.WordsCount, i.Indeces         
         FROM dbo.tWordsFromKladr w
            JOIN dbo.tWordKladrItems wi ON wi.ID = i.wordID                 
            JOIN dbo.tFoundWords f ON f.WordFromKladr = w.WordFromKladr
            JOIN dbo.tKladrItems i ON wi.kladrItemID = i.id ),
   CTE As
 (SELECT KladrItemName _KladrItemName, 
      WordPositionKladrItem _WordPositionKladrItem, 
      WordPositionAddressString _WordPositionAddressString, 
      StartPosition _StartPosition ,  
      EndPosition _EndPosition,
      Metric _Metric, IsConstruction _IsConstruction,
      WordsCount _WordsCount,
      Indeces _Indeces,
      WordPositionAddressString _StartWordIndex ,
      WordPositionAddressString _EndWordIndex,
      1 _StepNumber     
   FROM Sub T    
    UNION ALL    
 SELECT KladrItemName, WordPositionKladrItem, WordPositionAddressString,
      CASE WHEN StartPosition < _EndPosition 
            THEN EndPosition ELSE _EndPosition END, -- Max
      CAST(Metric + _Metric AS numeric(20, 10)),
      IsConstruction + _IsConstruction, 
      WordsCount, Indeces,
      CASE WHEN _StartWordIndex  WordPositionAddressString 
           THEN _EndWordIndex ELSE WordPositionAddressString END, 
      1 + _StepNumber
 FROM Sub Tab
    JOIN CTE                
       ON Tab.KladrItemName = CTE._KladrItemName        
          AND Tab.WordPositionKladrItem > CTE._WordPositionKladrItem        
          AND Tab.WordPositionAddressString >  CTE._WordPositionAddressString)
SELECT DISTINCT _KladrItemName KladrItemName,
    _StartPosition  StartPosition,  _EndPosition EndPosition,
    _Metric  SumMetric,_IsConstruction SumIsConstruction,
    _Indeces Indeces 
FROM CTE
WHERE_StepNumber = _WordsCount    
    AND (_IsConstruction = 0 or (_IsConstruction = 1 and _WordsCount > 1))        
    AND _EndWordIndex - _StartWordIndex + 1 = _WordsCountoption     
 (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: Your quite welcome... As an aside, although you are of course free to format and code as you find most agreeable, it kinda goes without saying that the more readable and clear the SQL in your question is, the more participation and help you are going to get from the other people on this forum.  There are some generally accepted techniques for making long SQL statements more readable...  Although I am by no means implying that how I formatted yr SQL above is best, please notice for example, the table aliases I added to your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
WITH base_table AS (
    SELECT wki.KladrItemName, 
           fw.WordFromAddressString, 
           fw.WordFromKladr, 
           fw.WordPosition AS WordPositionAddressString,
           tfk.wordNumber AS WordPositionKladrItem,
           fw.StartPosition,
           fw.EndPosition,
           fw.Metric,
           fw.IsConstruction,
           wki.WordsCount,
           wki.Indeces
      FROM dbo.tWordsFromKladr tfk
      JOIN dbo.tWordKladrItems wki ON wki.wordID = tkf.ID 
      JOIN dbo.tFoundWords fw ON fw.WordFromKladr = tfk.WordFromKladr
      JOIN dbo.tKladrItems ki ON ki.id = wki.kladrItemID),
     cte AS (
     SELECT bt.*
      FROM base_table bt
     UNION ALL
     SELECT KladrItemName, 
            WordPositionKladrItem, 
            WordPositionAddressString, 
            CASE WHEN StartPosition  _EndPosition THEN EndPosition ELSE _EndPosition END -- MAX, 
            CAST(Metric + _Metric AS numeric(20, 10)), 
            IsConstruction + _IsConstruction,
            WordsCount, 
            Indeces, 
            CASE WHEN _StartWordIndex  WordPositionAddressString THEN _EndWordIndex ELSE WordPositionAddressString END,
            1 + _StepNumber
       FROM base_table)
...
```